# Gas Transport Problem

Tags: ideal-gas, physical-chemistry, kinetic-theory, diffusion

I have a question that I thought would be a very simple effusion calculation that sent me down a massive rabbit hole after I tried to look it up in Landau's Physical Kinetics and so now I'm coming to you guys for help.

Let's assume you have two gas reservoirs at STP- arbitrarily, 1L in size each- which you connect with a long and thin tube that's still large relative to the mean free path of the gas- again arbitrarily, 1m long and 100 microns wide, imagine like an old-time barbell from a cartoon.  If the left reservoir is filled with Ar (40 amu) and the right reservoir has O2 (32 amu), then intuitively I would expect this system would approach a 50-50 Ar-O2 equilibrium incredibly slowly, since the gas can only diffuse through the tube and will mostly be mixing in this tiny interface.

Is there any way to quantify a characteristic timescale of mixing, say the time for the left vessel to reach 75% Ar-25% O2?  I feel like I'm missing some simplifying assumption that will make the problem an easy closed form instead of something requiring the solution of a transport equation or BBGKY hierarchy

Comment: The mixing will follow the Fick's laws for diffusion  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion, particularly the 2nd one: $$\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} = D\,\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial x^2}$$

Comment: How accurate do you want it to be? Is order of magnitude estimate okay?

Comment: Yeah, order of magnitude is fine.

Comment: @Poutnik- I know it will follow Fick's Law, what I'm asking about is the calculation of D, which I don't believe will be the simple argon-nitrogen number that you can look up in a table, since the mixing interface is very small compared to the volume of the gas.